# Get current URL and save to XML file

Tags: php, xml

and thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

I'm trying to get the current URL of the page and save it in the XML form. If I use the echo in the code, it shows the URL but the form doesn't replace the url in the XML.. what am I missing?

The code I'm using:

```html
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <?php
 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xml->formatOutput = true; 
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load('data.xml');

 //Get item Element
 $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('person')->item(0);  

 //Load child elements
 $name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
 $comment = $element->getElementsByTagName('comment')->item(0);
 $currentUrl = $element->getElementsByTagName('currentUrl')->item(0);

 //Replace old elements with new
 $element->replaceChild($name, $name);
 $element->replaceChild($comment, $comment);
 $element->replaceChild($currentUrl, $currentUrl);

 

 ?>
<?php
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') 
                === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;
echo $currentUrl;
?>

 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$name->nodeValue = $_POST['namanya'];
$comment->nodeValue = $_POST['commentnya'];
$currentUrl->nodeValue = $_POST['currentUrlya'];
htmlentities($xml->save('data.xml'));

 }

 ?>

 <form method="POST" action=''>
  name <input type="text-name" value="<?php echo $name->nodeValue  ?>" name="namanya" />
comment  <input type="text-comment" value="<?php echo $comment->nodeValue  ?>"  name="commentnya"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currentUrlya" value="<?php echo $currentUrl->nodeValue  ?>">

 <input name="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>
```

and for the XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventors>
  <person>
    <name>david</name>
    <comment> yes, so powwow</comment>
    <currentUrl>http://google.com</currentUrl>
  </person>
</inventors>
```

Based on Joe's comments I changed it to:

```html
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <?php
 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xml->formatOutput = true; 
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load('data.xml');



$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') 
                === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;


 //Get item Element
 $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('person')->item(0);  

 //Load child elements
 $name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
 $comment = $element->getElementsByTagName('comment')->item(0);
 $currentUrl2 = $element->getElementsByTagName('currentUrl')->item(0);

 //Replace old elements with new
 $element->replaceChild($name, $name);
 $element->replaceChild($comment, $comment);
 $element->replaceChild($currentUrl2, $currentUrl2);

 ?>
 
<?php

?>

 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$name->nodeValue = $_POST['namanya'];
$comment->nodeValue = $_POST['commentnya'];
$currentUrl2->nodeValue = $_POST['currentUrlya'];
htmlentities($xml->save('data.xml'));

 }

 ?>

 <form method="POST" action=''>
  name <input type="text-name" value="<?php echo $name->nodeValue  ?>" name="namanya" />
comment  <input type="text-comment" value="<?php echo $comment->nodeValue  ?>"  name="commentnya"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currentUrlya" value="<?php echo $currentUrl->nodeValue  ?>">

 <input name="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>
```

it still doesn't save the URL, though. any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `$element->replaceChild($currentUrl, $currentUrl);` looks odd.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means..

Comment: You're replacing the child node with itself. I guess you meant something like `$currentUrl->nodeValue = $currentUrlString`, where `$currentUrlString = $protocol . '://' . …`

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks.. I'm only a beginner in this, and I thought that as the other child nodes were similar ($name for example) and it worked with those, so it would be the same for the current URL.. how can I structure it so it will actually save the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your code emits a `Notice: Trying to get property 'nodeValue' of non-object in …`

The reason is, that you are overriding the `$currentUrl` DOM node variable with a string value `$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . …`. 
Therefore, setting the new DOM node value later with `$currentUrl->nodeValue = …` will fail.

Always use different names for different things. And keep watching your error log – it should generally stay empty.

Comment: if I change " $currentUrl2 = $element->getElementsByTagName('currentUrl')->item(0);" and " $element->replaceChild($currentUrl2, $currentUrl2);" and then, "$currentUrl2->nodeValue = $_POST['currentUrlya'];" .. how does the code refers the date back to the xml? I'm missing a piece here..

Comment: You error log is a text file – you can simply watch it using the `tail` command on Linux/Unix or `Get-Content` on Windows. `$xml->save(…)` writes the XML representation of your current DOM document. Everything fine with that. If you need the XML as string, use `$xml->saveXML()`.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks again, I edited the original question to show the changes.. the way it works now it simply deletes the currentUrl string in the xml and doesn't save the new URL.. could you please take a look again?

Comment: You're still using `$currentUrl->nodeValue` in your HTML form instead of `$currentUrl2` (a better name would be `$currentUrlElement` for example, as it describes what it is).  Again, the error log could have hinted you in the right direction.

Comment: yes, I noticed it after posting the edit, but even then, how do I get the $currentUrl2 to be equal to the pulled URL ($currentUrl) and saved in the xml? 
I'm self-taught so everything I do is trial and error..